# Class function does not change member variables permanently

Tags: c++, algorithm, scheduling

I'm trying to implement the FCFS<sub>First in, first out (FIFO), also known as first come, first served (FCFS)</sub> algorithm in C++.

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class Process{
public:
  static int count;
  static int cycle_count;
  int id;
  int at;
  int wt;
  int tat;
  int bt;

  Process(){
    id = count++;
  }

  void compute(){
    if (cycle_count < at){
      cycle_count = at;
    }
    cycle_count += bt;
    tat = cycle_count;
    wt = tat - bt;
  }

};

float average_wt(int n, vector<Process> v){
  float avg = 0;
  for (Process i: v){
    avg += i.wt;
  }
  avg /= n;
  return avg;
}

float average_tat(int n, vector<Process> v){
  float avg = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    avg += v[i].tat;
  }
  avg /= n;
  return avg;
}

void print(int n, vector<Process> v){
  cout << "Process\tBurst Time\tArrival Time\tWaiting Time\tTurnaround Time" << endl;
  cout << "-------\t----------\t------------\t------------\t---------------" << endl;
  for(Process i: v){
    i.compute();
    cout << i.id << "\t\t\t" << i.bt << "\t\t\t" << i.at << "\t\t\t\t" << i.wt << "\t\t\t\t" << i.tat << endl;
  }
  cout << "Average Waiting Time: " << average_wt(n, v) << endl;
  cout << "Average Turnaround Time: " << average_tat(n, v) << endl;
  cout << endl;
}


bool sort_on_at(Process a, Process b){
  return a.at < b.at;
}

int Process::count = 0;
int Process::cycle_count = 0;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {


  int n;
  cout << "Enter the number of processes: ";
  cin >> n;
  vector<Process> process(n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    cout << "Process " << i << ":" << endl;
    cout << "\tArrival Time: ";
    cin >> process[i].at;
    cout << "\tBurst Time: ";
    cin >> process[i].bt;
  }

  sort(process.begin(), process.end(), sort_on_at);
  print(n, process);

  return 0;
}
```

The issues is that this code correctly print the waiting and turnaround time for the individual processes, but gives the average waiting and turnaround times as `0`.

The expected output:

```
Enter the number of processes: 3
Process 0:
    Arrival Time: 0
    Burst Time: 24
Process 1:
    Arrival Time: 0
    Burst Time: 3
Process 2:
    Arrival Time: 0
    Burst Time: 3
Process Burst Time  Arrival Time    Waiting Time    Turnaround Time
------- ----------  ------------    ------------    ---------------
0           24          0               0               24
1           3           0               24              27
2           3           0               27              30
Average Waiting Time: 17
Average Turnaround Time: 27
```

Actual output:

```
Enter the number of processes: 3
Process 0:
    Arrival Time: 0
    Burst Time: 24
Process 1:
    Arrival Time: 0
    Burst Time: 3
Process 2:
    Arrival Time: 0
    Burst Time: 3
Process Burst Time  Arrival Time    Waiting Time    Turnaround Time
------- ----------  ------------    ------------    ---------------
0           24          0               0               24
1           3           0               24              27
2           3           0               27              30
Average Waiting Time: 0
Average Turnaround Time: 0
```

I did try some debugging, and found that the `compute()` function does change the values,(because it prints the correct values for the individual processes) but for some reason the `wt` and `tat` values are `0` for all the processes in the `average_tat()` and `average_wt()`.

Please let me know if I can make anything more clear.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: @RSahu I know I shouldn't use it, but I'm lazy, lol

Comment: One of the nice things about a vector is that you can always get it's size using `v.size()`. So you don't need to have all the functions where you pass in a vector and it's size, you just need the vector.

Comment: @john I know about the `v.size()`, but this code was written using arrays I'm trying to refactor the code, and then I ran into this problem.

Comment: @nullptr OK, refactoring is good, just make sure you complete it by removing the unnecessary parameters.

Comment: Revert the last step after which this misbehaviour started. You obviously broke something while refactoring. That said, your question is off-topic here, because you'd have to extract a [mcve]. In case you didn't, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wt` is calculated in the `compute` method, but this operates on a *copy* of `Process`:

```
for(Process i: v){  // a copy is made
  i.compute();
```

You need to use a value reference (`&i` in this case) to work on original `Process` stored in the vector, then `wt` will be saved.

```
for(Process& i: v){
  i.compute();
```

Comment: It works. I had no idea looping like this made a copy. What if I use the traditional loop. `for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)` and call `v[i].compute()`. Does that work on the same object?

Comment: As an addition to the above, it's really a very bad idea to be doing computation in a function called `print`. Don't surprise the readers or users of your code by putting functionality in places they don't expect.

Comment: @nullptr Yes it does because `v[i]` returns a reference.

Comment: @nullptr Traditional loop will be working fine. You can see [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) about for-range loop to get more details how it works.